# Default model binder freaks out when explicitly defining controller parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to figure out the model binding in MVC3. Look at this example.

Here's the controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Person person = new Person{ Name = "Test" };

        return View(person);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Edit(Person personModel)
    {
        return string.Format("From server: {0}", personModel.Name);
    }
```

And here's the html/javascript bit:

```
@model MCV3.Test.Models.Person
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){

        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        $.ajax({
            url : "/Person/Edit", 
            type: "Post",
            datatype: "json",
            data :  model, 
            success: function (data) {                   
                $("#result").text(data);                    
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="result"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above works, but if I change data setting of the ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
            url : "/Person/Edit", 
            type: "Post",
            datatype: "json",
             data : {personModel : model},
            success: function (data) {                   
                $("#result").text(data);                    
            }
        });
```

it doesn't work any more: the model is of the correct type, but the name property is null.

In the example that works, the post parameters are:

```
Name    Test

Name=Test
```

But in the example that doesn't work, they are:

```
personModel[Name]   Test

personModel%5BName%5D=Test
```

It seems like MVC can't serialize the request if it looks like this: `personModel[Name] Test`

Is there any way to solve this without writing a custom binder?

Comment: data : {personModel : model}, isn't valid JSON, you should pass it through as data: {"Name":"Test"}, that is a valid JSON string to pass through to the person object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MVC binding tries to create and populate a `Person` object to pass to your `Edit` action, it tries to find values for all the settable properties on the `Person` object; in this case the `Name` property. It therefore looks in the form data, query string data (etc.) for a name value pair with the key 'Name'. Your working example has one, your non-working example doesn't.

If you want to post data in this format you could create a custom [`ValueProvider`](http://mgolchin.net/posts/19/dive-deep-into-mvc-ivalueprovider) which parses the data and returns values based on what it finds.